# how i should create a reference of a object of a class

Tags: c#

How i get address pointer of a object

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28VS.71%29.aspx) code you can use [pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28VS.80%29.aspx). Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
// assume class Point { public int x, y; }
// pt is a managed variable, subject to garbage collection.
Point pt = new Point();
// Using fixed allows the address of pt members to be
// taken, and "pins" pt so it isn't relocated.
fixed ( int* p = &pt.x )
{
    *p = 1; 
}
```

However you should probably avoid doing this unless you understand what you are doing and know why you need this feature.

Comment: Thanx 4 reply......But i want this code in C#

Comment: @vishal_niist: That code I posted *is* in C#.